# Why was my answer converted to a comment? What is a link-only answer?

Tags: discussion, faq

A moderator just converted one of my answers to a comment. I don't understand; I solved OPs question by pointing him in the direction of a tool I think will solve his problem.

Why isn't this good enough?

Answer (score 3):

### This is not a "support" site.

This may come as a surprise, as our question-and-answer database is all about supporting our users and community. And we do, obviously :-)

But we are not a "support" site in the sense that e.g. a forum like Community is. We (and any site on the Stack Exchange Network) have very modest goals: *to be the first and only stop on your Search journey*. We try to record the best *questions* with the best *answers* for "eternity".

So while your answer might very well have been a here-and-now *solution* to the OPs problem; if your answer cannot stand on its own without the links - our mission fails. We end up with a question, and an answer that is only valid here and now. Assuming the linked resource remains (and they do not).

In other words. *It's fine*. But what we really need from people participating, is the patience and time invested to help us *actually record the good answers*.  Take the time, please.

This is why we reject answers that cannot stand on their own. And answers that do nothing but link elsewhere. They may *solve* a problem, but they do not *answer* a question.